# How do I hit Tell-style jump bursts?

Tags: in-the-groove

In Tell Expert, there are lots of sixteenth note bursts that end with a jump that requires double-stepping one of my feet. I don't see how to move the foot that double-steps fast enough to hit the jump, especially not when I have to move my other foot at the same time.

Tell is not the only chart that gives me this problem. It shows up on Energizer Expert and a couple of other charts as well.

What technique should I use to make these jumps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/inthegroove/comments/6qr57o/how_do_i_hit_tellstyle_jump_bursts/) suggests four strategies. From most consistent to least consistent (but roughly in order from most difficult to pull off to easiest), they are:

1. With the foot that needs to double-step a 16th to hit the jump, hit the sixteenth note with your toe, then hit the panel again with your heel on the following 16th note. This technique takes practice but can be used to get full Fantastic timing.
2. When you hit a jump in ITG, ITG uses the timing of the foot that hits later to determine which timing score to give the jump altogether. The timing window for registering a jump is generous. Taking advantage of this, hit the two sixteenths and the jump as a 24th burst. The first arrow will be a Fantastic, the second arrow will be an early Excellent, the third arrow is subsumed into the jump, and the final arrow completes the jump with a Fantastic.
3. To abuse timing windows even further, hit the two sixteenths as a jump. The second sixteenth will likely register as a Great. The other sixteenth and the jump will still register as Fantastic.
4. Just try to double-step the jump directly. Some people swear by this technique, but it is very difficult to pull off consistently for others.